# How to Send POST requests in View Components

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I am currently working on an ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC application (with Entity Framework), and I am trying to be able to perform CRUD operations without refreshing the page. As far as my research has taken me, it seems best to use View Components for this. I have the initial view component working (it renders the GET functionality), using the following code:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("AccountPhonesListEdit", new{accountNumber = Model.AcctNbr, typeOfCall = "Index", phoneId = -1})
```

where `InvokeAsync`works as a way to call the various CRUD functionalities for the view component controller, as so:

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(int accountNumber, string typeOfCall, int phoneId)
{
        switch (typeOfCall)
        {
            case "Create":
                await AccountPhonesCreate(accountNumber);
                break;

            case "Delete":
                await AccountPhonesDelete(phoneId);
                break;
        }

        return await AccountPhonesListEdit(accountNumber);
}
```

I have a button in my view component that, when clicked, should be calling delete. It works like this:

```
<button class="form-control bg-danger text-white" 
        onclick="@(async () => await Component.InvokeAsync("InvokeAsync", new{accountNumber = ap.AcctNbr, typeOfCall = "Delete", phoneId = ap.PhoneSequence}))">Delete</button>
```

When I click this button, the entire page refreshes, and the delete function is not actually performed. I don't believe there is anything wrong with my delete function, but just for context here is the delete function in the view component:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<bool> AccountPhonesDelete(int phoneSequence)
{
        var accountPhone = await _context.AccountPhones.FindAsync(phoneSequence);

        if (accountPhone != null)
        {
            _context.AccountPhones.Remove(accountPhone);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return true;
        }            

        return false;
}
```

Now, I've gone into debug mode to check the values of parameters when everything is called. When the original `InvokeAsync`to call the view component is called when the page first loads, the parameters for `InvokeAsync` are what we would expect -- AcctNbr, "Index" and -1, for accountNumber, typeOfCall and phoneId respectively. However, when I call the delete function with the button click, the same parameters -- AcctNbr, "Index" and -1 -- are passed in! Why is this? How can I get my View Component to properly call CRUD operations without reloading the page? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you examined the rendered HTML for the button? What does it look like?

Comment: Since you've tagged MVC, you'll need to do the submission with JavaScript and not through server-side C# code in your views. The Razor C# code is executed when the page is rendered and sent to the client.

Comment: Can you share more code or add [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it would be easier to tell. I'm not sure, at this stage.